# Flip boxes work in chrome but not Safari - jQuery or Css issue?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, safari

I have created some flip boxes on a website, that work great - In Chrome, but for some reason they are not working in Safari. I am very new to javascript, I actually had some amazing help on Stack Overflow to create these flip boxes. I just can't figure out if this is javascript, css or another issue.

If you want to check it out the site is [www.dangoodeofficial.co.uk](http://www.dangoodeofficial.co.uk) and the flip boxes in question are the SAX and DJ section at the top - the "MORE INFO" button triggers the flip.

I tried using Debugger in safari but I don't really know what I am looking for.

Any help would be really great. Thank you.

**CSS**

```
.flip3D {
float: left;
display: block;
position: relative;
width: auto;
height: 675px;
}
.flip3D .front {
position: absolute;
-o-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg);
-moz-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg);
-ms-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg);
-webkit-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg);
transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg);
-o-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
transition: -o-transform .5s linear 0s;
transition: -moz-transform .5s linear 0s;
transition: -ms-transform .5s linear 0s;
transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
width: 100%;
}   
.flip3D .back {
position: absolute;
-o-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 180deg);
-moz-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 180deg);
-ms-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 180deg);
-webkit-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 180deg);
transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 180deg);
-o-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
transition: -o-transform .5s linear 0s;
transition: -moz-transform .5s linear 0s;
transition: -ms-transform .5s linear 0s;
transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
width: 100%;
}
.flip3D .front.flip {
-o-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( -180deg);
-moz-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( -180deg);
-ms-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( -180deg);
-webkit-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( -180deg);
transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( -180deg);
}
.flip3D .back.flip {
-o-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg);
-moz-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg);
-ms-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg);
-webkit-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg);
transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg);
}
.flip3D2 {
float: left;
display: block;
position: relative;
width: auto;
height: 675px;
}
.flip3D2 .front2 {
position: absolute;
-o-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg);
-moz-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg);
-ms-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg);
-webkit-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg);
transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg);
-o-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
transition: -o-transform .5s linear 0s;
transition: -moz-transform .5s linear 0s;
transition: -ms-transform .5s linear 0s;
transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
width: 100%;
}
.flip3D2 .back2 {
position: absolute;
-o-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 180deg);
-moz-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 180deg);
-ms-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 180deg);
-webkit-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 180deg);
transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 180deg);
-o-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
transition: -o-transform .5s linear 0s;
transition: -moz-transform .5s linear 0s;
transition: -ms-transform .5s linear 0s;
transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
width: 100%;
}
.flip3D2 .front2.flip2 {
-o-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( -180deg);
-moz-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( -180deg);
-ms-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( -180deg);
-webkit-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( -180deg);
transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( -180deg);
}
.flip3D2 .back2.flip2 {
-o-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg);
-moz-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg);
-ms-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg);
-webkit-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg);
transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg);
}
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {       
jQuery('.flip-btn-1').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
jQuery(".front").toggleClass('flip');
        jQuery(".back").toggleClass('flip');
    });
});

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {       
jQuery('.flip-btn-2').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
jQuery(".front2").toggleClass('flip2');
        jQuery(".back2").toggleClass('flip2');
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the vendor prefixed properties of `backface-visibility`.

Currently you have them written as:

```
-webkit-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
-o-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Rewrite all those rules as:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
-o-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

This should fix your problem in Safari as it will pick the value from the `-webkit` vendor prefixed CSS property.

Answer (score 1):

> i think this is css issue because css on safari sometime dont work
>   properly. its work at safari and chrome.

`Try It`

[Demo](http://codepen.io/ijlalkhanzada/pen/ojoVGG)